# Python, going through a list and calculating how much values are in there

Tags: python, discord.py

currently having this error:

```
@tasks.loop(seconds=5)
async def adMessageSend():
channel = client.get_channel(786258218925293629)
await channel.send(adMessage)
```

`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'` 
The bot has access to the channel, and this function only runs when the bot is ready, so im unsure why it cannot find this channel?

Comment: Did you define intents?

Comment: is your channel object null? its probably a problem with client.get_channe()

Comment: @Nurqm I don't need intents for what I am doing.

Yes, channel is null, but im unsure why.

Comment: Your id value might be wrong, i would double check your id value again to make sure it is the right one

Comment: Its definetly right, I've copied it 5 times

Comment: upon further inspection, it appears my on_ready function was named incorrectly, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You have to define the intents. If you look at the [API References](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Intents.guilds), you can see that in order to use `client.get_channel()`, you have to define it.

```py
from discord.ext import commands
import discord

intents = discord.Intents().all()
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='', intents=intents)
```

Comment: I do not need to define intents. This issue has been resolved, you do not need to define intents for doing things which do not require intents, thanks anyway.

Answer (score -1):

```
@tasks.loop(seconds=5)
async def adMessageSend():
    channel = client.get_channel(786258218925293629)
    await channel.send(adMessage)
```

if you indent your last two lines, it should work just fine for you so long as your variables are defined